# Perl: subroutine parameter parsing: @ARG vs Underscore: @_

Tags: perl

When it comes to naming and parsing the parameters in a perl subroutine, is there any difference between the

`@ARG` and `@_`?

Answer (score 2):

You can increase memory consumption and slowdown regular expressions in old interpreters with implicitly exported `use English;` versions of match variables ($`,$',$&).

This [thread](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11113603) will be useful.

And read more about matchvars pitfalls at:

`perldoc English`

`perldoc perlvar`

`perldoc perlre`

I don't know about other issues.

Comment: That is, to use `@ARG` you enable it with `use English`. Prior to v5.20, that could slow down programs with lots of regexes because remembering `$&` is slow. That's been fixed for several year though. For older versions, you can `use English qw(-no_match_vars)`, as noted in its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no. See [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/perlvar.html#General-Variables)

> - @ARG
> - @_

> Within a subroutine the array @_ contains the parameters passed to that subroutine. Inside a subroutine, @_ is the default array for the array operators pop and shift.